# Using multiple parameters as arguments for Doctrine's SUBSTRING() function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, oracle12c

I think I've encountered a Doctrine bug, but I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this, or if maybe I'm missing something silly:

```php
// in controller
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Project::class)->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p.id')
    ->addSelect('SUBSTRING(:foo, 1, :pos) AS substrField')
    ->setParameter('foo', 'foobar')
    ->setParameter('pos', 3)
;

dump($qb->getQuery()->getResult());
```

The generated PDO query ends up passing `3` as the value for the `:foo` parameter and `"foobar"` as the value for the `:pos` parameter, which results in an Oracle `Invalid Number` error. If I swap the values in the `setParameter` methods it works:

```php
->setParameter('pos', 'foobar')
->setParameter('foo', 3)
```

Intentionally swapping the values in my `setParameter` calls feels way too hacky, so I'm using the helper `$qb->expr()->substring()` as a work around, which works as expected.

*Platform: Doctrine 2.5.14 with an Oracle 12c Database (12.2.0.1.0)*

I've opened a bug issue on Doctrine ORM with a little more detail [here](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8119)

Comment: this really does sound buggy, I took a quick peek into the doctrine/dbal code and couldn't find anything that indicates swapping of arguments, maybe I looked at the wrong code though.

Comment: @Jakumi yeah, it's odd. I looked [here](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/AST/Functions/SubstringFunction.php) and didn't see anything obvious either. I'm wondering if it has something to do with it assuming the 2nd and 3rd arguments are arithmetic values, so passing a string like `:pos` throws it off? I'm also curious if this is specific to Oracle or not. If I get time I may try it out on docker with MySQL to see if I can replicate it on a different database.

Comment: according to the code I looked at, it doesn't seem db-specific, because `SUBSTRING` is a doctrine token which is translated into different db platform specific versions. however, the function gets the same paramters in the same order for all of them, and it looks okay for them as well. also, the arithmetic values are parsed in a way, that a placeholder is okay, both `:...` as well as `?` are okay. so that should be no problem. (Parser: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php, it descends to arithmeticPrimary -> case `Lexer::T_INPUT_PARAMETER`)